# How to disable the render function in jquery datatable with condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have shown my `datatable` jquery below.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    DataTable(
    'StudentDetails',
    'student Details',
       [
       { "data": "StudentName", "name": "StudentName", "autoWidth": true },
       {
         "orderable": false,
         "searchable": false,
         "className": 'text-right',
         "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return '<a class="btn" href="UserLevels/' + full.StudentName+ '">Details</button>' +
                   '<a class="btn" href = "UserLevels/' + full.StudentName+ '/Edit">Edit</a>'; 
                    }
              }
          ],
          [

          ],
           'StudentDetails/LoadData',
            );
        });
```

Here i want to disable the `buttons` (Details,Edit) inside the `<a>` tag when the `studentName` is "Admin".
Any ideas ???

Comment: just use ternary base condition and then put this code $('#disableanchor').attr("disabled","disabled");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of disabling the button, don't bind it if `StudentName` is `Admin`.  You can check `StudentName` before bind buttons like below:

```
"render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
  if (full.StudentName != 'Admin') {
    return '<a class="btn" href="UserLevels/' + full.StudentName + '"> Details </button>' +
           '<a class="btn" href = "UserLevels/' + full.StudentName + '/Edit"> Edit </a>';
  } else
    return '';
}
```